# How to make an extension in NetLogo 5.x return a value of "nobody"?

Tags: java, netlogo

I've created some methods that allow me to use extensions to take a turtle/breed variable as a string and return the value (number, boolean, string, object (e.g. list/table).  However, I want it to fail safe and return "nobody" if the turtle/breed does not possess the variable name.

I can't get anything to turn Java's null into NetLogo's nobody however such that in the NetLogo environment nobody(1) from the netlogo world and nobody(2) as returned form the extension) are the same.. i.e.:

nobody(1) = nobody(2) is true

Some of the code:

```
import org.nlogo.api.*;
import org.nlogo.agent.Agent;
import org.nlogo.agent.AgentSet;
import org.nlogo.agent.Patch;
import org.nlogo.api.Nobody$;

public void load(PrimitiveManager primitiveManager) throws ExtensionException {
    primitiveManager.addPrimitive("get-variable-by-name", new GetVariableByName());
}

public static class GetVariableByName extends DefaultReporter{
    public String getAgentClassString() {
        return "OTPL";
    }

    public Syntax getSyntax() {
        return Syntax.reporterSyntax(
                new int[] { Syntax.AgentType(), Syntax.StringType() },
                Syntax.WildcardType());
    }

    public Object report(Argument[] args, Context arg1)
            throws ExtensionException, LogoException {

        Agent a = (Agent) args[0].get();
        String name = (String) args[1].get();

        Object value = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.getVariableCount(); i++ ){
            if (a.variableName(i).compareToIgnoreCase(name) == 0){
                value = a.getVariable(i);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (value instanceof Double){
            return (Double) value;
        }
        else if (value instanceof Boolean){
            return (Boolean) value;
        }
        else if (value instanceof String){
            return (String) value;
        }
        else if (value == null){
            return Nobody$.MODULE$;  // I've tried several things here, but none work.  This the last attempt.
        }
        else {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return Nobody$.MODULE$;` is correct, I believe. It doesn't work?

Comment: It did work this time.  Strange, I tried it multiple times (and other variations) and never got the returned 'nobody' to be equal to the NetLogo 'nobody' before.  I rebuilt the extension and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that

```
return Nobody$.MODULE$;
```

is actually correct.

Why it wasn't working for you at first is hard to guess. After you rebuild your extension, it's necessary to either restart NetLogo or use the `__reload-extensions` command for your changes to take effect — maybe you weren't doing that?

Comment: I usually close the program and restart.  I suspect that I didn't get the extension jar with the correct code copied into my extensions folder properly.

Thanks again for the help!